# После отработки Ajax перестаёт работать скрипт отображения видео YouTube

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, youtube

Есть сайт на WordPress, тема ListingPro. Развернул функционал: заменил отображение обычных миниатюр объявлений на видео с YouTube. Получилось так, когда находишься на категории, подгружаются сразу много видео с YouTube, и что бы увеличить скорость загрузки страницы я использовал следующий скрипт:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
            div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            div.onclick = labnolIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(div);
        }
    });

function labnolThumb(id) {
    var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg">',
        play = '<div class="play"></div>';
    return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}

<div class="youtube-player" data-id="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_cat", true).'" style="width:100%;height:152px"></div>
```

ID видео отображается через произвольное поле.

Всё работает хорошо, пока не начинают применять фильтр этих объявлений. Фильтры работают через Ajax. И после отображения отфильтрованных объявлений перестаёт работать данный скрипт. Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка (причина)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ajax вам снова нужно запустить функцию

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadContent);

function loadContent(){
    var div, n,
        v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
        div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        div.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(div);
    }
}

function labnolThumb(id) {
    var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg">',
        play = '<div class="play"></div>';
    return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}

// Например применили какой-то фильтр и выполнели ajax
$('.filter').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        /****/
        success: function(data){
            // Что-то делаете с данными
            // И вызываете функцию
            loadContent();
        }
    })
    return !1;
});
```